# 'docker exec' command is not working

Tags: virtualization, docker

When I tried to start a stooped container using `docker exec`command, it shows command not found. How can I run the container again?

```
sudo docker exec -it 26a6ce216479 /bin/bash
Error: Command not found: exec
Error: Command not found: -it
```

Comment: Is there a `docker exec` command? The [`docker` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/docker.1) doesn't list it. Try [`docker attach`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/docker-attach.1)

Answer (score -1):

`docker exec` is used to spawn a process inside an already running container. I guess the command you are looking for is `docker start`.

Comment: But how can I enter to the container?

Comment: thankyou for the response Andreas Veithen.Now the command is working properly. When I upgrade docker to new version it starts working. docker exec command will support in new versions only.(>1.3)